# Selective run android tests on different devices

Tags: android, robotium

My Android app has some Activities slightly different for Phone and tablets. I"m writing automation using JUnit, Android SDK and Robotium. What would be the best way to selective execute tests based on device connected?

Comment: This question is is to broad.  Give some ideas of what you have tried so far and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've done automation for phone and now planning to extend same test project for tablet. Since, some Activities in tablet are different from phone, I'm looking for a way to detect connected device and just execute right test sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could detect if your test device is phone or tablet during testing. So your test application will contain:

1. One test class which will determine the screen size and decide which tests should be done
2. A lot of functions (with input parameter Solo solo). This functions are the tests which you have now.

Your test class could call appropriate functions to test phone or tablet.

See [how to get screen size](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotium-developers/UwVB4F5Cq2Q).

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method will be to tag the tests that are phone only with an @PhoneOnly annotation and the tablet ones with @TabletOnly annotation and then run different adb commands on different device types:

To do this view the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html

Specifically

> Filter test run to tests with given annotation: adb shell am
>   instrument -w -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation
>   com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
>
> If used with other options, the resulting test run will contain the
>   union of the two options. e.g. "-e size large -e annotation
>   com.android.foo.MyAnnotation" will run only tests with both the
>   LargeTest and "com.android.foo.MyAnnotation" annotations.
>
> Filter test run to tests without given annotation: adb shell am
>   instrument -w -e notAnnotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation
>   com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner